# Google analytics push custom channel grouping

Tags: google-analytics

Is it possible to push custom channel group into Google analytics in a similar way as events? For events I use this code:

```
_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Popup - displayed', 'Popup displayed - Popup Id 5', 'This is popup title']);
```

Now I want to push new custom channel group Popup displayed each time user get served popup so I can compare results with Organic search without popup, Direct traffic without popup with organic search with popup.

I would like to accomplish something like this:
[image]

Tnx!

Answer (score 0):

With the current Google Analytics version you could use a [set call with your tracker object](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/tracker-object-reference#set) to overwrite campaign data and then create a custom channel definition that matches your custom data:

```
trackers = ga.getAll();
tracker = trackers[0];
tracker.set('campaignMedium', 'withPopup');
```

No idea how you would do this with your version of Analytics which is deprecated. Also this may have side effects (like loosing the original campaign data).

However you may simply create two segments, one for users who have seen the event and those who have not. Since you can select multiple segments this allows for a comparison without changing anything in the code.